# snackBar type widget with two actions

Tags: java, android

since android doesn't allow 2 buttons on SnackBars  do we have any equivalent widget with two buttons on it ? and the most important which should not interrupt the workflow of UI something like this : [image] but more like SnackBar

please help

Comment: So where is the `coding` part ?

Comment: what you want man ? am asking for any libraries , clues to go with,  what you wanna see ?  how i create SnackBar which am not going to use at all

Comment: oh.. okay ! I Sorry :) My Bad .apologies !

Comment: no thats fine , just so pissed off , after shifting from iOS to android  things are hard here or maybe am retarded :D

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use two Actions in a Snackbar, you should use Dialog as shown in the following image:

[Material Design Guidelines - Snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlEnS.png)